# How to remove a comment using AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to write a comment `destroy` method to remove comments on a page using Ajax (with no page reload).

Here's what I've tried.

**posts/show.html.erb**

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
   <div id="comment_<%= comment.id %>">
      <p><strong><%= comment.user.username %></strong></p>
      <p class="comment"><%= comment.comment %><p>
      <%= link_to "Delete", [@post, comment], method: :delete, remote: true %> 
   </div>
<% end %>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) 
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy 

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to post_path(id: params[:post_id])}
  format.js 
end
```

I'm not sure what else I need but I tried this

**posts/destroy.js.erb**

```
$('#comment_<%= @comment.id %>').remove();
```

Any help is appreciated! According to the server logs, the comment is being removed when I click delete, but the JS is not removing the comment on the front end.

Comment: Why are you using posts/destroy.js.erb when your controller is CommentsController? What happens if you put destroy.js.erb into /views/comments/?

Comment: @praszyk seems like that's the glitch

Comment: paste the js code in `comments/destroy.js.erb`

Comment: Solved, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Rails will always try to render a view that matches your controller and action names. In your case, since you're destroying the comment in the `comments_controller`, you must write your js code on the view `app/views/comments/destroy.js.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$('#comment_<%= @comment.id %>').remove();`

To

```
$('#edit_comment_<%= @comment.id %>').remove();
```